# Axis2 and Rampart lib from ver 1.6.1 to 1.7.6/1.7.1 respectively

Tags: java, upgrade, apache-axis, rampart

I am using legacy Axis2 web services. So, far it was running fine and now we are planning to upgrade Axis2 version from 1.6.1 to 1.7.6 and rampart lib version from 1.6.1 to 1.7.1. Any suggestion as what is best approach to do it, since this is legacy system so we dont have lot of information. I have been trying to copy all the jar and mar but doesnt seem to be working.

Is there any steps that needs to be followed to do it the right way.